# ImportError on tensorflow module while running Bazel script for Skip-thoughts model training

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, bazel

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7 and Tensorflow 1.4 installed in it. I am stuck with this Bazel script to pre-process text datasets for training i.e in this part of the [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/skip_thoughts).

```
# Run the preprocessing script.
bazel-bin/skip_thoughts/data/preprocess_dataset \
  --input_files=${INPUT_FILES} \
  --output_dir=${DATA_DIR}
```

where I get this error,

```
$ bazel-bin/skip_thoughts/data/ preprocess_dataset --input_files="./skip_thoughts/dataset/*.txt" --output_dir="./skip_thoughts/data"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/code/skip_thoughts/bazel-bin/skip_thoughts/data/prep
rocess_dataset.runfiles/__main__/skip_thoughts/data/preprocess_dataset.py", line 43, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

The error occurs only when I run the Bazel script and tensorflow works fine otherwise. Any suggestions on what might be wrong will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you follow these steps to install TF? https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux

Comment: Thank you for looking into this and for the suggested answer. The issue was with the Anaconda installation on a cluster machine that was with Python 3.5 and couldn't locate this. I had to change the code from Python 2.7 and then everything worked smoothly.